# Remove directories from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, web, directory, url-masking

I've been searching around and tried many different ideas to fix the state of a URL for my client, but have had no joy.

The URL currently looks like this:

```
website.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.php
```

My client wants this to be showing much like the other links on the website as so:

```
website.com/page
```

I'm fine with removing the .php that's simple enough and is already written into my .htaccess file. It's just removing the 3 directories from the URL is what I cannot work out.

Before anyone asks about moving the file to a higher directory, I'm afraid this cannot be done as everything needs to be down in this 3rd directory for this page.

I believe my latest attempt is about the closest I've got to solving this, if anyone could point out my mistakes and a solution it would be much appreciated:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder1/folder2/folder3/(.*)$ /page$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

After researching more today, I think I may have confused people with this question. I think what I should have said is that I need to mask the URL, hiding the 3 directories, and showing just the domain and the page itself.

I still seem to be hitting a wall with masking too. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

After a whole weekend (and quite a bit of the week between working) I finally managed to succeed with what I wanted.

The site now displays as required:

```
website.com/page
```

Which has been redirected and masked from:

```
website.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.php
```

The piece of code required in the .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /folder1/folder2/folder3/page.php
```

Looks like I was being stupid before and had the syntax backwards, but all is well now and I'm allowed to sleep :)

Hope this helps anyone else in future with this sort of problem!